# Php how to include in a variable name another variable

Tags: php

In the example are two arrays, but actually may be other number of arrays (i do not know how many arrays i may have).

```
$some_name = array ( "Volvo_0",220,180, );
$array_name_for_variable[]='some_name';//here i create another array latter to loop through

$another_name = array ( "Volvo_1",221,181, );
$array_name_for_variable[]='another_name';
```

In the example i just want to print_r the arrays i may have. So i loop through `$array_name_for_variable`. Like

```
foreach( $array_name_for_variable as $i_array_name_for_variable => $val_array_name_for_variable ) {
```

trying to print particular array (like `print_r($some_name)`), using this

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($['val_array_name_for_variable'], true), '</pre> $val_array_name_for_variable __<br/>';
```

but see error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'`

```
}
```

This `print_r($['val_array_name_for_variable'])` is wrong. Tried this `print_r( $[$val_array_name_for_variable] );`. Also got error.

Any ideas what need to change.

Why all this and what i need...

I have 12 arrays, but i do not know which of 12 would be used in one particular page.

So page loads, some of the 12 arrays are defined (used).

I may write like if array_1 exists, then long html code using variables from the array_1.

Then again if array_2 exists and not empty, then repeat the same html code with variables from array_2.

But instead of copy-paste (repeating) html code i decided to loop through arrays existing in opened page and the long html code write only once.

Comment: You can't use $['xxx'] this is because you need a name of the variable meaning you can have $var['xxx'] but not just $['xxx'] as PHP wouldn't know which array you are trying to access with $var['xxx'] it would know you want the value for key xxx in array $var.

Comment: its very hard to understand what you trying to achive

Comment: Would the result be `some_name`, `$val_array_name_for_variable __`, `another_name` and `$val_array_name_for_variable __`?

Comment: @Dwza. Edited question and tried to explain why i need all this and what i want.

Comment: doesn't all arrays exist on page load?

Comment: @Dwza On page load fetch data from mysql. 12 conditions and there may be 12 arrays with data from mysql. Each array has its own name. I do not know how many arrays will fetch from mysql (may be 2 and may be 12).

Comment: could you may give a sample of selecting data from mysql and creating arrays ? because somewere the array names have to come from :) depending on this you may just have to create a multidimensional array and loop your through this and create your html.

Comment: @user2118559 I've edited my answer to comply with the new information you provided. Check it out. See if it helps. Also please provide the whole user flow of what happens. How could the arrays exist on one page and not on the other? Are they user inputed, taken from somewhere based on some user input? If so, then how are they added to $array_name_for_variable?

The best way might be to not use foreach but a for loop starting from 0 until 11 (making 12 passes at the array in total) and check each one for any values (Like the new code I posted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve the problem with:

```
$some_name = array ( "Volvo_0",220,180, );
$array_name_for_variable[]=$some_name;

$another_name = array ( "Volvo_1",221,181, );
$array_name_for_variable[]=$another_name;
```

then iterate through it:

```
foreach( $array_name_for_variable as $i_array_name_for_variable => $val_array_name_for_variable ) {
echo '<pre>', print_r($val_array_name_for_variable, true), '</pre><br/>';
}
```

This will print all the elements in $array_name_for_variable.

Comment if you need any more changes to the output.

Explanation: What the code is actually doing is iterating through all elements of the array $array_name_for_variable. They it creates a key => value for each element in it. The value ($val_array_name_for_variable) on the first iteration would be: $some_name. The key ($i_array_name_for_variable) - the element position in the array, so on the first iteration it would be 0 (as it always start from 0).

If you don't need the element position you could do it like this:

```
foreach( $array_name_for_variable as $val_array_name_for_variable ) {
echo '<pre>', print_r($val_array_name_for_variable, true), '</pre><br/>';
}
```

It would generate exactly the same output as the previous code snippet.

For adding elements to the array you have to pass a variable and you were passing just a string.

**EDIT:**
Based on the newly added info the code should be:

```
foreach( $array_name_for_variable as $i_array_name_for_variable => $val_array_name_for_variable ) {
if (array_key_exists($i_array_name_for_variable, $val_array_name_for_variable)) {
echo '<pre>', print_r($val_array_name_for_variable, true), '</pre><br/>';
} else {
//Code if the array does not exist.
}
}
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do something like this

```
$some_name = array ( "Volvo_0",220,180, );
$array_name_for_variable['some_name']= $some_name ;

$another_name = array ( "Volvo_1",221,181, );
$array_name_for_variable['another_name']= $another_name ;


foreach( $array_name_for_variable as $i_array_name_for_variable => $val_array_name_for_variable ) {

   print_r($val_array_name_for_variable);//prints the array
   print_r($i_array_name_for_variable);// print the keys ex :- some_name
}
```